# SQL Trigger UPDATE, INSERT Case Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

What is the correct syntax to create a SQL Trigger that updates another table the updated or inserted values AND a field to specify whether it was an UPDATE or INSERT.

Example of what I want to do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table1_Trigger_Update_Insert 
ON Table1
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO Table2 (col1, col2, col3)
        SELECT 
            col1, col2,
            CASE WHEN {if it was an update} THEN 'UPDATE'
                 WHEN {if it was an insert} THEN 'INSERT'
            END
        FROM
            Table1
```

Comment: Suspect this needs to be two separate triggers, one for update and one for insert

Comment: Yes, I currently have 2 triggers. (Also I meant to say UPDATE and DELETE, although it shouldn't matter). I would like to put it all in one if possible tho.

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace trigger table1_trigger_update_insert 
after update or insert or delete
on table1
for each row
declare
 v_operation varchar2(16) := '';
begin

    if inserting then
        v_operation := 'insert';
    elsif updating then
        v_operation := 'update';
    elsif deleting then
        v_operation := 'delete';

insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3)
select col1
      ,col2
      ,v_operation
from table1
..
..
..
..
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

(I added the [[image]sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) tag based on the user's previous question history and am writing this answer assuming SQL Server).

Triggers that fail to reference the `inserted` (and/or `deleted`) pseudo-table are broken. Your current one fails to mention either, but inserting references to both makes this quite easy:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Table1_Trigger_Update_Insert 
ON Table1
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO Table2 (col1, col2, col3)
        SELECT 
            col1, col2,
            CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) THEN 'UPDATE'
                 ELSE 'INSERT'
            END
        FROM
            inserted
```

We use `inserted` rather than `Table1` to obtain *just those rows that were affected by the `INSERT` or `UPDATE`*. We reference `deleted` to determine whether the action was an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` (and default to `INSERT` if we fail to detect an `UPDATE` since those are the only possible actions that cause this trigger to fire)

The specific logic for detecting the `UPDATE` breaks in the specific case of an `UPDATE` that affects 0 rows (which will still cause the trigger to fire). But happily, in that case, we'll have 0 rows in `inserted` anyway and so not be inserting any rows into `table2` anyway.